# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на image ( уже с загруженной картинкой) тот становился невидимым

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на одну из этих картинок, та становилась - невидимой

```js
const cvs = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
const fon = new Image();
const boy = new Image();
const book1 = new Image();
const book2 = new Image();
const flower1 = new Image();
const flower2 = new Image();
const flower3 = new Image();
const meal = new Image();
const paper = new Image();
const pen = new Image();

pen.src='img/pen.gif';
paper.src='img/paper.gif';
meal.src='img/meal.gif';
boy.src='img/boy_stay2.png';
fon.src='img/fon3.jpg';
book1.src='img/books2.gif';
book2.src='img/books.gif';
flower1.src='img/flower1.gif';
flower2.src='img/flower2.gif';
flower3.src='img/flower3.gif';

const Draw=()=>{
    ctx.drawImage(fon, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(boy,350, 170);
    ctx.drawImage(meal,650,0);
    ctx.drawImage(book1, 300,0);
    ctx.drawImage(book2, 720,130);
    ctx.drawImage(flower1, 30,358);
    ctx.drawImage(flower2, 20,100);
    ctx.drawImage(paper, 200,420);
    ctx.drawImage(pen, 350,460);
    ctx.drawImage(flower3, 20,0);
    requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
};

flower3.onload = Draw;
```

Comment: То, что отрисовывается на canvas уже нельзя назвать image, это зона на канве, куда переносятся данные из изображения. При переносе данных вы можете воспользоваться расширенным синтаксисом `ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);` Если каждое последующее изображение не перекрывает сколько-нибудь предыдущие, то `sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight` и есть координаты каждого изображения на канве. Их можно проверять при клике на канву в перебором в цикле всех "изображений".

Comment: С другой стороны, если проверять координаты в обратном порядке добавления, то и отслеживать перекрытия не надо будет). Получайте ширину и высоту изображений после загрузки (каждого в отдельности), масштабируйте сообразно задумке и вписывайте в канву по рандому, сохраняя данные в некий массив данных об этих изображениях. При клике перебирайте координаты и проверяйте.

Comment: @Leonid да, классный костыль (+классно минусуешь)

Comment: @Vadim ни разу вам не минусовал. Но посмотрите внимательно на вопрос: автор пытается отрисовать на canvas несколько изображений в разных позициях, а затем хочет удалить с канвы изображения, по которым кликнул. А у вас просто сами изображения как DOM элементы.

Comment: @Leonid спасибо что ты нам не минусовал. Ну потому-что так проще их контролить, лучше раз сетку адаптивную сделать, чем в канвасе расставлять пихели

Comment: @Vadim я не имею мнения по этому поводу, я просто угадываю почему люди ставят минуса)) Всё остальное расскажет автор вопроса, почему он стал рисовать на канве и почему решил так неудобно обращаться с изображениями)

Comment: Просто я любитель, пересмотрел пару видео уроков по JavaScript, и там игры делали через канвас, правда событие клика не было. На носу был проект и я решил сделать его в JavaScript, я понятие не имел почему это событие не происходит, перерыл интернет и ничего не нашел, но теперь уже ясно)

Comment: @J.S. для игор, лучше использовать другой язык, жс изначально для пользовательских нажимашек сделан, это сейчас существует нода и можно сервера делать.. но, касаемо игр на жс, если на то пошло, лучше смотреть в сторону - phaser.js\three.js или похожих штук

Comment: Ясно, буду знать)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Канвас их "погружает в себя", так что клик будет `по канвасу`, можно через *костыли*, но проще сделать так как я написал ниже:

На нативе

```js
const cvs = document.getElementById('notcanvas');
const gif1 = new Image();
const gif2 = new Image();

gif1.src = 'https://i.gifer.com/ZlXo.gif';
gif2.src = 'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/BestGlassButterfly-small.gif';

gif1.onclick =()=>{
    gif1.remove();
}
gif2.onclick =()=>{
    gif2.remove();
}

gif2.onload=()=>{
    cvs.appendChild(gif1);
    cvs.appendChild(gif2);
};
```

```css
body{
    background:#232323;
}
```

```html
<div id="notcanvas"></div>
```

Либо вот, на jquery в несколько строк

```js
const gif1 = `<div id="picture"><img src="https://i.gifer.com/ZlXo.gif"></div>`;
const gif2 = `<div id="picture"><img src="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/BestGlassButterfly-small.gif"></div>`;

$('#notcanvas').append(gif1,gif2);
$('#notcanvas').on('click', '#picture', ({currentTarget})=>{
    $(currentTarget).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
body{
    background:#232323;
}

div#notcanvas > #picture {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notcanvas"></div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!) А то я весь интернет перерыл, ничего не нашел и голову ломаю почему у меня событие клик не работает))

Comment: @J.S. Для большего понимания, [на](https://habr.com/ru/post/305900/) тоже самое на http://learn.javascript.ru имеется в *другом ключе*

Comment: Один минус поставил я. Ответ не отвечает на вопрос автора - как удалить\сделать невидимым изображение на canvas.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ответ решает проблему человека, без костылей. И завязки на канвасе у человека еще нет.

Comment: @Vadim у человека проблема с канвасом, в примере написан код с канвасом, в вопросе указан канвас. ТС хочет сделать игру, на канвасе. А вы говорите, нет завязки на канвасе? :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko `.src .drawImage` (две строки) не завязка, игру делают при помощи движков, слайды можно сделать и через див

Comment: @Vadim все с вами понятно :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko и нам с тобой, No matter how small :)